# Class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

I want to compute the class number of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$, the result should be $1$.

The discriminant $d_K$ is $24$, so the Minkowski bound is $M_K = \sqrt{6} < 3$. So every ideal class contains an ideal in $\mathcal{O}_K$ with ideal norm less than or equal to $M_K$.

I know that $2$ is a norm of the principal ideal $(2 + \sqrt{6})$, in fact $2 = -N(2 + \sqrt{6})$. This is a principal ideal, so the class number is $1$.

Now I wonder if one can, after computing $M_K$, see that the class number is $1$ by knowing that $2$ is ramified (because $6 \equiv 2 \bmod 4$)? That means $2 \mathcal{O}_K = P^2$ for a prime ideal $P$.

Comment: The question is closed for answering, but the answer to your class 1 claim is "No". $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-5}]$ has Minkowski bound between $2$ and $3$, and $2$ is ramified because the fundamental discriminant (with $-5\not\equiv1\bmod4$) is $4×(-5)=-20$, but the class number is $2$. Ramification does limit the generating ideal to contributing no more than a twofold transposition to the class group, so in this case you know the class number is $1$ or $2$. But that is as far as you can go with this argument.